# Java. How do I add more colours to paint?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a drawing app and so far i am able to choose from two colors(Green and Black) and two shapes (Circle and Square). I want to add more colors to paint with but i couldn't figure out how to add more than 2 colors.

These are the classes I'm using.

```
public class DrawLinesActivity extends AppCompatActivity
 {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawshapes);
        DrawLines d = new DrawLines(this);
        setContentView (d);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuItem menu1 = menu.add(0, 0, Menu.NONE, "Green");
        MenuItem menu2 = menu.add(0, 1, Menu.NONE, "Black");
        MenuItem menu3 = menu.add(0,2, Menu.NONE, "Pixel Brush");
        MenuItem menu4 = menu.add(0,3, Menu.NONE, "Smooth Brush");

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case 0:
                colours.fill = 0;
                return true;
            case 1:
                colours.fill = 1;
                return true;
            case 2:
                colours.shape = 0;
                return true;
            case 3:
                colours.shape = 1;
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
}
```

...

```
public class DrawLines extends View
{
    Canvas c;
    Paint paint;
    Bitmap bmp;
    Random g;
    float X, Y;

    public DrawLines(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        g=new Random();

        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        bmp= Bitmap.createBitmap(1050,1650,conf);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle (Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor (Color.WHITE);

        this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {

                float x, y;

                c = new Canvas (bmp);
                x = event.getX ();
                y = event.getY ();
                System.out.printf ("%f %f\n", X, Y);

                paint.setAntiAlias (true);

                if (colours.fill == 0)
                {
                    paint.setStyle (Paint.Style.FILL);
                    paint.setColor (Color.GREEN);

                    if (colours.shape == 0)
                        c.drawRect (x, y, x + 50, y + 50, paint);
                    else
                        c.drawOval(new RectF (x, y, x + 50, y + 50), paint);
                }
                else
                {
                    paint.setStyle (Paint.Style.FILL);
                    paint.setColor (Color.BLACK);

                    if (colours.shape == 0)
                        c.drawRect (x, y, x + 50, y + 50, paint);
                    else
                        c.drawOval(new RectF (x, y, x + 50, y + 50), paint);
                }

                paint.setColor (Color.WHITE);

                invalidate ();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas c)
    {
        super.onDraw (c);

        c.drawBitmap (bmp, 0, 0, paint);
    }
}
```

...

```
public class colours
{
    static public int shape = 0;
    static public int fill = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, make sure the user can access other colors. Let's try adding red.

```
MenuItem menu1 = menu.add(0, 0, Menu.NONE, "Green");
MenuItem menu2 = menu.add(0, 1, Menu.NONE, "Black");
MenuItem menu2 = menu.add(0, 2, Menu.NONE, "Red"); //Make an item for red.
MenuItem menu3 = menu.add(0, 3, Menu.NONE, "Pixel Brush");
MenuItem menu4 = menu.add(0, 4, Menu.NONE, "Smooth Brush");
```

Next, assuming from how your code works, it handles it via the `fill`attribute of `colours`. If `fill` is 0, it's green, else, it's black. Lets add a case `1`, which will be red.

```
if (colours.fill == 1)
{
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    ...
}
else if (colours.fill == 0)
{
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    ...
}
else
{
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    ...
}
```

We should also make sure to add a case for `Red` in the button tap code area:

```
...
case 0:
    colours.fill = 0;
    return true;
case 1:
    colours.fill = 1;
    return true;
case 2:
    colours.fill = 2;
    return true;
case 3:
    colours.shape = 0;
    return true;
case 4:
    colours.shape = 1;
    return true;
...
```

You might see i put `Red` as 2 and pushed the brush settings further. This is to make sure the colors are grouped.

Now, this is all I can suggest from the code you supplied. Maybe there's more to it. But you should take a look at this.